# How to join 3 queries with different date range conditions?

Tags: sql

I would like to combine the following 3 queries into 1, and display in a table which will have 9 columns ([Col A]- [Col I]), where [Col I] = [Col H] + [Col F]. However, I failed to join them into single query. Can anyone please guide me on this?

```
select ve.ItemNo_ AS [Col A],sum(ve.qty) AS [Col B], sum(ve.actualsales) As [Col C], sum(ve.actualcost+ve.expectcost) As [Col D]
from ve
left join(
    select ssh.No_ 
    from ssh
    join sh
    on sh.No_ = ssh.OrderNo_
    where sh.DocType=1 and sh.OrderDate >='2017/05/01' and sh.OrderDate <='2018/05/31'
    ) psh
on ve.DocNo = psh.No_
where ve.EntryType=1 and ve.ItemNo_ like '%' and ve.PostingDate >= '2018/06/01'
group by ve.ItemNo_
```

```
select ve.ItemNo_,sum(ve.qty) AS [Col E], sum(ve.actualsales) As [Col F], sum(ve.actualcost+ve.expectcost) As [Col G]
from ve
left join(
    select ssh.No_ 
    from ssh
    join sh
    on sh.No_ = ssh.OrderNo_
    where sh.DocType=1 and sh.OrderDate >='2017/05/01' and sh.OrderDate <='2018/04/30'
    ) psh
on ve.DocNo = psh.No_
where ve.EntryType=1 and ve.ItemNo_ like '%' and ve.PostingDate >= '2018/05/01'
group by ve.ItemNo_
```

```
SELECT SUM(sl.salesamount) AS [Col H]
FROM sl
INNER JOIN sh
ON sl.DocNo = sh.No_
WHERE sl.DocType = 1 AND sl.Type = 1 AND sl.No_ LIKE '%' AND sl.outstandingqty > 0 AND sh.OrderDate >='2017/05/01' AND sh.OrderDate <='2018/04/30'
```

Comment: Your first and second query  uses no data from the right subquery of the left join. Why join at all?

Comment: I will need to retrieve the data which is based on the OrderDate from sh table, and match the ssh.No_ with ve table.

Comment: Probably you want INNER JOIN then.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
DECLARE @colH DECIMAL;

SELECT @colH = SUM(sl.salesamount)
FROM sl
INNER JOIN sh ON sl.DocNo = sh.No_
WHERE sl.DocType = 1
 AND sl.Type = 1
 AND sl.No_ LIKE '%'
 AND sl.outstandingqty > 0
 AND sh.OrderDate >= '2017/05/01'
 AND sh.OrderDate <= '2018/04/30';

SELECT [Col A]
 ,sum([Col B]) AS [Col B]
 ,sum([Col C]) AS [Col C]
 ,sum([Col D]) AS [Col D]
 ,sum([Col E]) AS [Col E]
 ,sum([Col F]) AS [Col F]
 ,sum([Col G]) AS [Col G]
 ,@colH AS AS [Col H]
 ,(sum([Col G]) + @colH) AS [Col I]
FROM (
 SELECT ve.ItemNo_ AS [Col A]
  ,sum(ve.qty) AS [Col B]
  ,sum(ve.actualsales) AS [Col C]
  ,sum(ve.actualcost + ve.expectcost) AS [Col D]
  ,0 AS [Col E]
  ,0 AS [Col F]
  ,0 AS [Col G]
 FROM ve ON ve.DocNo = psh.No_
 WHERE ve.EntryType = 1
  AND ve.ItemNo_ LIKE '%'
  AND ve.PostingDate >= '2018/06/01'
 GROUP BY ve.ItemNo_
 
 UNION
 
 SELECT ve.ItemNo_ AS [Col A]
  ,0 AS [Col B]
  ,0 AS [Col C]
  ,0 AS [Col D]
  ,sum(ve.qty) AS [Col E]
  ,sum(ve.actualsales) AS [Col F]
  ,sum(ve.actualcost + ve.expectcost) AS [Col G]
 FROM ve
 WHERE ve.EntryType = 1
  AND ve.ItemNo_ LIKE '%'
  AND ve.PostingDate >= '2018/05/01'
 GROUP BY ve.ItemNo_
 ) data
GROUP BY [Col A]
```

Comment: I tried and found that the ssh table is missing from the query and I have 2 different orderdate range, which are `sh.OrderDate >='2017/05/01' and sh.OrderDate <='2018/05/31'` and `sh.OrderDate >='2017/05/01' and sh.OrderDate <='2018/04/30'`